# Dropwizard - Validation with Hibernate validator returns 400 instead of 422

Tags: dropwizard, hibernate-validator

I have a resource like so...

```
public Class  Offer {


          String name;

      @NotNull
       String id;


       Date start;


      Date end;


    //getters and setters
    }
```

and a resource class method like this

```
@POST
@Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/offers")
public Response createOffer(@Valid Offer offer) {
 //blah
}
```

My input is something like this:

```
{
  "id" : "someId"

}
```

This gives a http 400 Bad request back from Jetty, whereas I expect something like 422 Unprocessable entity - name cannot be null

What could I be doing wrong?

On Dropwizard 0.8.1

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer which was a mistake in my yaml file. The answer is documented here

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/gWvnYuKpz2c